# How to know date format of Users

Tags: apex, visualforce

How to know the date format of the user in salesforce.
Basically I want to perform some operation based on user's date format.
Like:

```
  If(date_format == dd/mm/yyyy)
{
   do this
}
if(date_format == mm/dd//yyyy)
{
   do this
}
```

I know we can use Map to store the locale as key and date format as values and then query the locale and get the date format, but it is very lengthy and it will also increase the no. of lines in code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're going about this the wrong way. What are you actually *trying* to accomplish?

Comment: To expand on what @sfdcfox suggests, inferring something about the user from a date format will lead to unpredictable behavior given there are potentially 100's of date formats, some locale-based, some completely arbitrary. So knowing the specifics of what your end goal is will help come up with a solution.

Comment: Actually in my vf page I'm using custom solution to show the standard Date and Time functionality like standard one.
So based on the user locale setting I need to store that date-time in my field.
Right now it is working fine for Locale other then US. As US date format is MM/DD/YY so if I am giving date in DD/MM/YY format then it is storing today's date to 2016 date.

Answer (score 1):

To see the date format of your company instance, you can just use date.format() //on any date field It will give you the date format set in your salesforce instance.

other than that you can use Userinfo.getlocale() to get the locale of the current user.

If you want to capture date and time in your VF page with the format just use System.now.format()